# Looking to insert a clickable image in a video with php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Hi I am looking to insert a clickable image in a video. to make a video interactive.
Basically I have a form with 3 fields upload-video, upload-photo and a URL. What I am looking for is that when the user uploads these 3 fields the image will become the part of the uploaded video and upon clicking that image it will open a URL that was added in the form.
after that I have to provide the embed code of that interactive video to users.
Is there any way to achieve that functionality with php? I have looked into ffmpeg but I am not sure that it will do exactly what I need.

Comment: You can't click on a video more than you can make a picture play sound.

Comment: What happens when you absolutely position the "image" on top of the video with a higher z-index?

Comment: thanks for your response. So there is no way to achieve this.?

Comment: I want that image to become part of that video. so other users can integrate it also on their site with the embed code. Not to move it over the video.

Comment: Your "embed code" could technically have that bit of instruction in the src link, to be rendered as such via javascript. Provided the z-index trick works. ... But i see now your point, reliance on ffmpeg and the how-to in that fashion.

Comment: Not with a regular video container. There're surely other kind of formats that offer that feature (perhaps PowerPoint) but not raw video ones.

Comment: @GetSet can you explain it further that how a small instruction in the "embed code" can add the image onto the video on the users website?

Comment: I can @mudassarqureshi. However i dont want to design your app for you. The crucial question (unanswered so far) that i asked you was what happens when you absolutely position an image on top of the video. That was the hint if you were to go in that direction.